# Unclear curl option -o <filename#1>. What exactly does '#' do?

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I want to download several files and use variables in their filenames using Curl.

e.g.: 
`curl https://curl.haxx.se/docs/{companies,whodocs}.html -o "file_#1.txt"`

I am using curl 7.61.1

From Curl man-page I have that `#number`in the filename should be substituted by some string. So I assume I should get `file_companies.txt` and `file_whodocs.txt` but in my case this command just downloads `file_#1.txt` and prints the second file to stdout (like without `-o <filename>`). So I am left wondering how to use this option.

Any explanation would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You have to use one `-o` per URL, and I can't get the advertised substitution working either. `wget https://curl.haxx.se/docs/{companies,whodocs}.html` might be a better option.

Comment: Yes, I know that normally there's one `-o` per URL, but in that case I have to specify ALL filenames and I can't use the variable substitution. Using `wget`, I think, just works in case the `{}` expansion is in the end of the URL. According to Curl docs it should also work somewhere in the middle of the URL.

Comment: Yup, that's apparently what you have to do if you're using curl.

Comment: Won't wget run into problems with same files on different URLs, like: `www.example.com/test/file.txt` and `www.example.com/test-two/file.txt`?

Comment: It'll create `file.txt` and `file.txt.1` by default, I believe. Also see the `-x` option for putting them in a directory tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bash's brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) gets in the way. You should quote `{ ... }`.

```
$ curl 'https://curl.haxx.se/docs/{companies,whodocs}.html' -o "file_#1.txt"

[1/2]: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/companies.html --> file_companies.txt
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 29316  100 29316    0     0   5097      0  0:00:05  0:00:05 --:--:--  7540

[2/2]: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/whodocs.html --> file_whodocs.txt
100  2528  100  2528    0     0  23849      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 23849
```

The `{companies,whodocs}` gets expanded by bash into two arguments:

```
$ echo curl https://curl.haxx.se/docs/{companies,whodocs}.html -o "file_#1.txt"
curl https://curl.haxx.se/docs/companies.html https://curl.haxx.se/docs/whodocs.html -o file_#1.txt
```

That's not what you want. You want to pass `{...}` literally, as it is, to curl. You need to quote it.